# Codeigniter: Add username variable to the session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Hi all I'm trying to add the username field from the users table in the session when the user is logged. 
The session is saved in the database.
 
But I get these two messages:

Severity: Notice 
 
Message: Undefined variable: username 
 
Filename: controllers / main.php 
Line Number: 43

Severity: Notice 
 
Message: Undefined index: username 
 
Filename: controllers / main.php 
Line Number: 45

Where am I wrong? And 'all day I'm trying to figure out where I'm wrong. 
Thanks in advance.
 
**this is my model:**

```
function getDataProfiloUtente($username) {

    $query = $this->db
            ->where('username', $username)
            ->limit(1)
            ->get('users');
    return $query->row();
}
```

**this is my controller:**

```
$utente['records'] = $this->model_users->getDataProfiloUtente($username);
        $data = array(
             'username' => $utente['username'],
             'is_logged_in' => 1
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

**this is my views:**

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
$query->row();
```

Actually returns an object you can use instead (in your model):

```
return $query->row_array(); //this return an array instead of an object
```

In your controller:

```
//notice I removed the ['records'] index when assigning, 
//there's no need to store the result into an array
$utente = $this->model_users->getDataProfiloUtente($username);
```

Then access to the column/field using object or array notation :

```
 //if you use row() in your model
$utente->username;

//or if you used row_array in your model do:
//$utente['username'];
```

[From CI documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) :

> row()
>
> This function returns a single result row. If your query has more than
>   one row, it returns only the first row. **The result is returned as an
>   object.** Here's a usage example

**Also notice** you're saving the result into another array, if you need to do it in that way you will have to do something like:

```
//if use row() and store the result in your array $utente['records']
$utente['records']->username;
```

Or

```
//if use row_array() and store the result in your array $utente['records']
$utente['records']['username'];
```

Comment: You explain it perfect! +1

Comment: Now I get the following errors: 
Severity: Notice 
Message: Undefined variable: username 
Filename: controllers / main.php 

while in view this error: 
Severity: Notice 
Message: Array to string conversion 
Filename: views / members.php 
Line Number: 50

Comment: from your advice, I'm using row_array () in the model 
and this code in the controller: 

$ user ['username'] = $ this-> model_users-> getDataProfiloUtente ($ username); 
             $ data = array (
                  'username' => $ user ['username'], 
                  'is_logged_in' => 1 
             ); 

             $ this-> session-> set_userdata ($ data);

Comment: sorry this is code correct:$utente['username'] = $this->model_users->getDataProfiloUtente($username);
            $data = array(
                 'username' => $utente['username'],
                 'is_logged_in' => 1
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);

Comment: Change `'username' => $utente['username'],`to `'username' => $utente['username']['username']`   you're still saving the result from your model into an array position ($user['username']) you don't need to do that (at least you want or have that requirement), I did udpate my answer with those details.

Comment: Also if you can add the line number to your code that will be nice, just to be sure about something.

Comment: sorry I did not understand, I always get the same errors.

Comment: Now in the model: return $ query-> row_array ();

Comment: Now controller: $utente = $this->model_users->getDataProfiloUtente($username);
            $data = array(
                 'username' => $utente['username'],
                 'is_logged_in' => 1
            );

Comment: I always get the same error error + a new one Message: Undefined variable: username
Filename: controllers/main.php and Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: controllers/main.php

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are assigning array to another array with index `records` so to get your username you must do:

```
$data = array(
    'username' => $utente['records']['username'],
    'is_logged_in' => 1
);
```